# The line $ y=x/3+5$ is a tangent to a circle with centre $(-2,1)$. Find the equation of the circle

Tags: circles

I've been given this as a question for my maths AS homework but don't understand how to start. I understand that you need to find the radius to complete the equation but don't know how to do this. So far I have worked out that $(x+2)^2+(y-1)^2=r^2 $ Any Ideas of what to do next?

Comment: Find the distance between the center and the line, the distance is the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** find the equation of the line perpendicular to $y=\frac13x+5$ and passing through $(-2,1)$. That line includes the radius from $(-2,1)$ to the point of tangency.

Answer (score 0):

The hint of Téophile suggests a possible approach.

If you want continue in your approach than note that the system
$$
\begin{cases}
y=\frac{1}{3}x+5\\
(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=r^2
\end{cases}
$$
has only one (double) solution if the line is tangent to the circle, and this is done only if the discriminant of the second degree equation that we find substituting $y$ from the first to the second equation is null.

This discriminant is a function $\Delta(r)$ of $r$  and solving the equation $\Delta(r)=0$ you can find the value of $r$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of the line is
$$D\;:\;\; x-3y+15=0$$

the distance to the center gives the radius.

$$R=\frac{|-2-3+15|}{\sqrt{1^2+3^2}}=1$$

the circle's equation is

$$(x+2)^2+(y-1)^2=1$$